# Why $curl\textbf{u}$ is twice the axial vector $\omega$ of the skew part of tensor $grad\textbf{u}$

Tags: operators, solid-mechanics

I met a problem in *Nonlinear Solid Mechanics: A Continuum Approach for Engineering* by Gerhard A. Holzapfel. This is the problem and the solution given bu the author.

---

[image]
[image]

---

My question is WHY $W_{ij}=\partial u_{j} / \partial x_{i}$. In my knowledge, $W=\frac12(A-A^T)$ and $W_{ij}=\frac12(A_{ij}-A^T_{ij})$, where $A=grad\textbf{u}$.
Thus $W_{ij}=\frac12(\partial u_{j} / \partial x_{i} - \partial u_{i} / \partial x_{j})$. So why the answer claims that $W_{ij}=\partial u_{j} / \partial x_{i}$? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They *define* ${\bf W}$ as a skew-symmetric tensor with entries
$$W_{ij}\equiv\frac{\partial u_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}.$$
When defining a skew symmetric tensor this way, there is an implied restriction that the definition only holds for $i<j$ (or $j<i$; it doesn't matter), with the remaining elements for which $i>j$ defined by "the index relation $W_{ji}=-W_{ij}$."  Those are just the definitions they use in the solution.

Those definitions are good enough to give the solution of that sample problem.  If you wanted to define ${\bf W}$ more systematically, it would make sense to use
$$W_{ij}\equiv\frac{\partial u_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}-\frac{\partial u_{j}}{\partial x_{i}},$$
but that definition is by no means universal.

Comment: Got your idea but it feels like abrupt to give a definition in this example without any statement about this in the previous text of this book.